# Android - how get orientation relative to the world

Tags: android, location, orientation, accelerometer, android-sensors

How can I get orientation relative to the world? I want to create a sort of compass that points always to 0, 0 coordinates. To do that, I need to get my phone orientation relative to the world.

I used [accelerometer sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion) , but I can see only my orientation compare to myself.

How can I get my rotation (orientation) like google maps?

[image]

Comment: If you want to see your orientation you should use the compass sensor, but not all devices have it. As alternative you can obtain the heading, only during the movement, using the GPS.